# Fixing syntax for UPDATE query with SELECT subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to `UPDATE` my dataset `WHERE` a `SELECT` condition is met using `Instr`.

```
UPDATE [Extract] SET [Type] = 'Main'
WHERE
SELECT Instr([Name],'Main')
FROM [Extract]>0;
```

I think it's possible to do this using my SQL above, but I am running syntax issues. How can I correct this?

Comment: Move your `>0` before `FROM`

Comment: I'd also suggest changing your field names `TYPE` and `NAME` to non-reserved words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to do your update to records where `[Name]` contains 'Main', you can do it in a simpler way without a `SELECT` at all.  Use `like()` and the `*` wildcard.  Like this:

```
UPDATE [Extract] 
SET [Type] = 'Main'
WHERE [Name] like ('*Main*')
```

`*` allows for any character string to exist on either side of the string 'Main'.